# How do I swap the CMD and ctrl key on a mac?

Tags: keyboard

I have been trying to switch the Ctrl and CMD key on my MacBook for a while, but nothing seems to work.

A lot of the answers say to go to System Settings > Keyboard Layout and change it there, but I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu, and it does not have that feature.

I've also tried adjusting the xmodmap, which works for the current session, but when I reboot, the settings aren't saved.

To try to save it, I have added the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to my Startup Applications, but that didn't work. I have also tried adding the command to the file `/etc/profile.d/myfile.sh` (I also altered the permissions). I have tried the file `~/.xinitrc` file and many other ways, but nothing seems to work.

However, when I go to my shell and type in `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, it works. So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The gnome-tweak-tool provides an option "Left Alt is swapped with Left Win". You may install gnome-tweak-tool with `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` and the option can be found in the "Typing" menu.

Answer (score 0):

To reload a configuration on login, first save it to the file:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

then edit the file created, such as:

```
keycode 37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
```

or viceversa.

You can run `xev` and press the buttons to verify their keycode.

Finally, edit the file  `~/.xsessionrc` (or create it if it does not exist) with the following text, and change execution permission:

```
chmod a+x ~/.xsessionrc
```

Content of `~/.xsessionrc` file:

```
#/bin/sh 
# 
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here) 

# read ~/.Xmodmap if it exists
if [[ -f "${HOME}/.Xmodmap" ]]; then
    xmodmap "${HOME}/.Xmodmap"
fi
```

Comment: If followed these instructions exactly, and it still didn't work

Comment: i have edited my answer replacing .xsession with .xsessionrc. Adding a command  `echo "test" > ${HOME}/test_file` after `xmodmap` command, runs correctly, therefore the `xmodmap` command is executed. But I believe that the settings are subsequently overwritten.

Comment: Ok, so there's been a new development, and I'm not totally sure why this is happening, but when I wake my computer from sleep, it goes to the log in screen, and then goes black, and goes back to the log in screen, and when I enter my password and try to log in, it gets stuck just displaying the background. However, when I  restart my computer it works fine.

Also, there's an error file called .xsession-errors now that says this:

Comment: Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning

Comment: init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped

Comment: I made a link to my bash history, so you can see if maybe it was something else I did https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DM5xyVXD-FFExOCscGfG5y1aM30i-skJF5bM9gqnp7I/edit?usp=sharing